# How to resize the design section of an ActiveReports Designer control?

Tags: c#, report, activereports

I'm developing an application (by C#) that has a part that enables the final user to design his self report.
It has an option to design automatically ActiveReports controls from a passed data source and shows it, but I can't resize the designe section's ruler to fit it's width.

**How can I resize the design section of the designer control programmatically?**

Answer (score 2):

Use ActiveReport.ReportWidth property to set section width (in inches) and respective Section.Height to set height.

In order to notify design-time infrastructure (ComponentModel and such) update the values using property descriptor, such as:

```
TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(report)["ReportWidth"].SetValue(report, 4f);
```